# zipping python library zipcodes

Tags: python, module

So I need to zip a bunch or modules together and I am usually able to do this pretty easily. I am trying to do it with the python zipcodes library and I have no clue how this is suppose to work and I'm getting a lot of trouble. This is what I did

1) downloaded tar file from https://pypi.org/project/zipcodes/#files

2) unpacked it to get the following folder structure

```
 -zipcodes-1.0.4
      -zipcodes 
         -__init__.py
         -zips.json.gz 
      -zipcodes.egg-info 
         -dependency_links.txt 
         -PKG-INFO 
         -SOURCES.txt 
         -top_level.txt
      -MANIFEST.in 
      -PKG-INFO 
      -README.rst 
      -setup.cfg 
      -setup.py
```

3) I rename the top level folder called zipcodes-1.0.4 to just zipcodes.

4) Compress the top level folder to a zip called zipcodes.zip

5) Write a script in the same dir with the following code:

```
import os, sys
if os.path.exists('zipcodes.zip'):
    sys.path.insert(0, 'zipcodes.zip')
else:
    sys.path.insert(0, './zipcodes')
import zipcodes
print(zipcodes.matching("12345")[0]['zip_code'])
```

6) When I run I get the error "zipcodes does not have attribute matching."

7) This method has worked for me when I package other modules like numpy and pandas but not this one for some reason.

I just can't seem a way to go about zipping this the correct way and accessing the functions in the **init**.py file. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?